# Importing excel data

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have an excel file with data in column A - ZZ, I am needing to import columns E,F,G,I into a table within a word document. I don't want to use mail merge as I want the data all within the same table within word. Can anyone give me any pointers? I have been looking for a while and testing code unsuccessfully.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rowCount2 As Long, shtSrc As Worksheet
Dim shtDest As Worksheet
Dim rng2 As Range


          
    Set shtSrc = Sheets("Roadmap")
    Set shtDest = ActiveDocument.Range(1)

    rowCount2 = shtSrc.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
         
    Set rng2 = shtSrc.Range("A1:A" & rowCount2)
       
    
    currentRow = 2

    For Each cell2 In rng2.Cells
        If cell2.Value <> "" Then
            shtDest.Range("B" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Value2
            shtDest.Range("C" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 1).Value2
            shtDest.Range("G" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 2).Value2
            shtDest.Range("H" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 3).Value2
            shtDest.Range("J" & currentRow).Value2 = cell2.Offset(0, 4).Value2
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
                
        ElseIf cell2.Value = "" Then
     
        End If
        Next cell2
        
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Your picture link shows blank. Please revise accordingly. Also show us what you've tried.

Comment: @L42 I attached the code I have been trying to use. Also, I keep attaching the picture but it will not show for some reason. It is a picture of the table in my word document. I am trying to move cell B,C,G,H,J from my excel file to the corresponding fields in my word table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(1).Cells(1).Range
Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application
Dim MyWB As Excel.Workbook
Set MyExcel = New Excel.Application
Set MyWB = MyExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\marci_000\Documents\Projekty\Almanach\NOTORIA_XLS\AGORA.XLS")

For i = 1 To 6
    ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(1).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("ConsQRT_Reports").Cells(3, 70 - i)
Next i

MyWB.Close False
Set MyExcel = Nothing
Set MyWB = Nothing
End Sub
```

I assume that in the first paragraph (`ActiveDocument.Range(1)`) you have one table (`ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1)`). The first `Debug.print` sends to Immediate window the content of the first cell (first row, first column).
Then I open an Excel file and for cells (from Excel) 69 down to 64, write contents of row 3 into the cells within the Word table.

After the job is done, `Close` the file in Excel and do cleaning (`=Nothing`) - otherwise you will have a bunch of "unfinished" and hidden instances of Excel.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin Nowicki - I get error "Compile Error: User-defined type not defined when I run this. Dim MyExcel As Excel.Application

Comment: Hi, It is a common problem. Just add reference to Microsoft Excel in tools,reference. Cheers

Comment: fixed that error. Now it is giving me Run-Time error, Automation error the interface is unknown. I updated the MyWB.Sheets to "Roadmap", the name of the tab where my data is.  ActiveDocument.Range(1).Tables(1).Range.Rows(1).Cells(i).Range = MyWB.Sheets("Roadmap").Cells(3, 70 - i)

Comment: My table has 6 columns and the loop goes from column 1 to column 6. Probably your table does not have enough space to fit the data.

Comment: Understood. When I add another column in my word doc, the macro does run. It just does not pull over any data. What is the Cells(3, 70 - i) doing? Data in my excel file starts on B1,C1,G1,H1,J1.

Comment: OK, my data is far on the right, namely speaking cells(3, 70 -i ) corresponds to cells "BQ3" down to "BL3". If your data is in cells B1 to J1, then the address to these cells will be ` MyWB.Sheets("Roadmap").Cells(1, i+1)`. There is i + 1 because you start from column B.   Cheers

Comment: AWESOME! Thank you! I have made some changes there and its now pulling back data, but its only pulling the first row of data from my excel file. From my understanding "Next i" should make it move to the next row, is that not right? I have tried next i + 1 and get errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73859/discussion-between-marcin-nowicki-and-daniel-strong).