# how to load data from excel to word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I want to implement the vba-code into my word-document:
how to load Cell(1,1) from sheet1 from a Excel-Document (lets say ist Path is C:\Test\Excel.xlsx) into current Word Document. In the word document already exist a table(2x2). Want to insert it into first cell of table.
Many thanks!

Comment: This is too broad of a question. What have you tried and where are you stuck? In any event, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29269818/4996248) (which is a virtual duplicate) might help.

Comment: Thanks! i ve already read that thread, but cannot find it helpful as i am a beginner. Just Need a simple Code for me for a start.

Comment: Perhaps you could do your best in making that example work and then ask a more focused question about your code if and when you run into difficulty. You are unlikely to get an answer which uses code which is much simpler than the code in the accepted answer (which is only 12 lines of code, much of which consists of variable declarations).

Answer (score 0):

> These solutions use late-binding to communicate Word - Excel

---

See here to [learn more about late vs early binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation)

---

### Steps to communicate from Word to Excel and insert the text back into Word.

Follow these steps:

In Word:

1) Insert a bookmark in your word's table cell and name it "FirstCell"

[image]

2) Add a module

[image]

3) Copy/paste this code and adapt the '<<< Customize this >>>' section

[image]

Code:

```
Sub InsertFromWordIntoExcel()

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Dim excelDocument As Object
    Dim bookmarkRange As Range

    Dim bookmarkName As String

    Dim excelWorkbookPath As String
    Dim exceWorkbookName As String
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim cellContentAddress As String

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    excelWorkbookPath = "C:\Test\" ' include backslash at the end
    exceWorkbookName = "Excel.xlsx"
    bookmarkName = "FirstCell"
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    cellContentAddress = "A1"

    ' Check if Excel is already opened
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Open a new instance
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.Visible = True
    End If

    ' Check if document is already open
    Set excelDocument = oExcel.Workbooks(exceWorkbookName)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Open excel workbook
        Set excelDocument = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(excelWorkbookPath & exceWorkbookName)
    End If

    ' Reset error handling
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Get the bookmark range
    Set bookmarkRange = ThisDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

    ' Insert the cells text
    bookmarkRange.Text = excelDocument.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellContentAddress).Value

    ' Add the bookmark again
    ThisDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, bookmarkRange

End Sub
```

---

### Alternative, to communicate from Excel and insert the cell's text into Word.

1) Add the bookmark in Word (as mentioned above)

2) Add a module in Excel

3) Copy/paste this code and adapt the '<<< Customize this >>>' section

```
Sub InsertFromExcelIntoWord()

    Dim oWord As Object
    Dim wordDocument As Object
    Dim bookmarkRange As Object

    Dim wordDocumentPath As String
    Dim wordDocumentName As String
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim cellContentAddress As String

    ' <<< Customize this >>>
    wordDocumentPath = "C:\Test\"  ' include backslash at the end
    wordDocumentName = "Word.docx"
    bookmarkName = "FirstCell"
    sheetName = "Sheet1"
    cellContentAddress = "A1"

    ' Check if Word is already opened
    On Error Resume Next

    Set oWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Open a new instance
        Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
    End If

    ' Check if document is already open
    Set wordDocument = oWord.documents(wordDocumentName)

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        ' Open word document
        Set wordDocument = oWord.documents.Open(wordDocumentPath & wordDocumentName)
    End If

    ' Reset error handling
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Get the bookmark range
    Set bookmarkRange = wordDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range

    ' Insert the cells text
    bookmarkRange.Text = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName).Range(cellContentAddress).Value

    ' Add the bookmark again
    wordDocument.Bookmarks.Add bookmarkName, bookmarkRange

End Sub
```

Comment: assume i dont give a bookmark.
Is there a way of identying a table using if. Like "search word document, if table found, insert A1 from sheet1"